# Android Activity transition compatibility

Tags: java, android, android-activity, transition

I'm trying to make a transition between two Activities, the following code **works with my Android 4.2.1 Device**, but **doesn't work in my 4.0.4**

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyClass.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    //transition
    overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.fade_out);
    //finish activity
    finish();
```

I really don't understand why it doesn't work on Android 4.0.4

Can you help me please ? thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't rely on android framework animations. Copy the code to res/anim/anim.xml & use without issues

Android framework animations can be found in framework repositories(google for some)